# Redirecting from example.com to www.example.com with AWS Cloudfront and S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I currently have my website running at https://www.example.com. I did this by creating an S3 bucket hosting the site called www.example.com, then I created a Cloudfront instance to add SSL.

I then created a CNAME in Godaddy which points to the Cloudfront URL.

If I visit http://example.com, GoDaddy correctly redirects to http://www.example.com, which Cloudfront correctly redirects to https://www.example.com.

HOWEVER, if I visit https://example.com, I get a blank page. How can I make the SSL naked domain redirect to www?

Answer (score 0):

Proved myself wrong in rereading your question:

“Unfortunately, our forwarding servers don't accept HTTPS requests. This is why your forward isn't working. Traffic coming into the forwarding server using the HTTPS protocol won't resolve. The only way you'd be able to set this up is to have the domain hosted on a server where it has an SSL Certificate installed. You could then set up a redirect to point traffic from your old domain to your new one. “

https://www.godaddy.com/community/SSL-And-Security/Forwarding-works-as-long-as-URL-does-not-contain-https/td-p/44951

You should probably just move the domain to route53.